# Error when using r.reclass in QGIS - GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am trying to run the `r.reclass` tool but I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 431, in processAlgorithm
>   Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
>
> File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 389, in executeGrass
>   for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
>
> File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1253.py", line 23, in decode
>   return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 25: character maps to

I changed the path in Windows but still I get the above error.

Do you know something about it and how can I fix it?

I am using the last version of QGIS 'A Coruna' 3.10.2.

Comment: What is the path to your working folder? Which Unicode Standard is your file encoded in, perhaps it is in `'ascii'`?

Comment: Hi Taras, how can I chech the path of my working folder? In terms of Unicode Standard, I do not know something about it.

Comment: `'path of my working folder'` means the full path to the folder where your layers are stored for which you are trying to execute `r.reclass`?

Comment: QGIS 3.10.2-1 or 3.10.2-2? Run the _OSGeo4W Setup_ app, _Advanced Install_, _Follow_ and _Follow_ until get the packages, search for `qgis` package, check what version package do you have. If you have `3.10.2-1` installed, it was packaged with some errors and you need to update it (one more _Follow_). If you have already `3.10.2-2`, you will need to report a bug.

Comment: Dear Gabriel. I checked it and I installed 3.10.2-2. I made a report but  I have not received an answer yet. Actually I made some changes such as I changed the language in regional settings in Windows which improve a bit the GRASS toolbox and when I run a tool but still when I run the tools the outputs cannot appeared. Do you know sth about it?

Comment: @Lampros, Hi. No, I will test 3.10.2 today. I was waiting to upgrade from 3.10.1 because of the announce of problems with the first 3.10.2 package. There was a similar behaviour before (in QGIS 3.4 I think), and changing Windows regional setting was a workaround, but I don't know if this is related with that or something with the data encoding. Do you have another layers to test the tool?

Comment: Now I am facing problem wiht SAGA toolbox as well. It says that execution completed but then it says the following: The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/AdvanceGIS/Workspace/Upslope.sdat</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm. I had this Problem with GRASS and Whitebox tools but now I am running some tools from SAGA and I have the same problem something that did not happen before.

Comment: Moreover, do you believe that there is a problem with the path? and if yes, what I should change? Because I do not use characters or spaces etc

Comment: @Lampros, The problems with the paths result when using special characters, the same as with names of layers or fields. If you are not using special characters, they should not bring you problems. The error in SAGA is very generic, sometimes an incorrectly used parameter generates an empty layer and returns that error, you could open a new question about that. In both this and that one, you should include the entire log and not just the error.

Comment: I run the r.watershed from GRASS and I got the following error again have a look

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
             File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass78\etc\grass78.py", line 2216, in 
             main()
             File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass78\etc\grass78.py", line 2092, in main
             create_initial_gisrc(gisrc)
             File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass78\etc\grass78.py", line 728, in create_initial_gisrc
             writefile(filename, s)

Comment: File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass78\etc\grass78.py", line 225, in writefile
             f.write(s)
             File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
             return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
             UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 34-40: character maps to 
             Press any key to continue . . .